# Grid Layout in Sass

Tags: css, sass, grid

Всем Доброго дня! Подскажите как применить правило Grid к всем child элементам в Sass

```
.grid *  { grid-column: md; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, чтобы применить правило ко всем child  элементам в сетке grid 
к примеру такое правило будет работать в css

```
    .grid { 
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns:
      [xl-start] 1fr [md-start] minmax(0, 624px) [md-end] 1fr [xl-end]; }
    .grid *  { grid-column: md; }
```

в Sass придется писать так:

```
    .grid
      display: grid
      grid-template-columns: [xl-start] 1fr 1.5rem [md-start] minmax(0, 624px) [md- end] 1.5rem 1fr [xl-end]
      > *
      grid-column: md
```